# Download youtube videos don't work in vget

Tags: java, youtube, download

one year ago I used [vget](https://github.com/axet/vget) library to download youtube videos. If I try it know, it doesn't work. When I reach `v.download();` method in example, it is working and doesn't end (like in loop). I use the last version of library `1.1.22`. Does anybody use this library without problems?

**example from home page**

```
package com.github.axet.vget;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;

public class DirectDownload {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // ex: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nj6PFaDmp6c
            String url = args[0];
            // ex: "/Users/axet/Downloads"
            String path = args[1];
            VGet v = new VGet(new URL(url), new File(path));
            v.download();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the sample url is not good, it should start with `https`

But even with this corrected url, it gives a 403 error (visible while debugging)

But with this video, it works perfectly : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yNpOz44RM20

So maybe there is an issue with some url.

Comment: Thanks. You are right, for some videos it works, for some it doesn't work. Probably in this library is an issue.

Comment: Yes, I agree, try to raise an issue if not already done https://github.com/axet/vget/issues

Answer (score 1):

Version 1.1.23 is having issues too as of July 2015. I guess Youtube keeps changing its security protocol and the authors of VGet need to make library changes so there is some delay. Someone has recently raised a ticket for this particular issue and we need to wait for an update:

https://github.com/axet/vget/issues/40

Maybe the library works for older videos because only new content is served with the new security protocol.